# TikZ: Using already defined \node label with decimal precision in \draw

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have labelled all my nodes in my code and some have decimal numbers in their labels. I want to use these labels as arguments in the `\draw` command but I keep getting this error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

Below is a minimum working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Putting node and clipping them to their respective positions
\foreach \x in {1/2,1,10/3,37/3,15.5}
    \foreach \y in {1,1.25,1.5,3,3.5,,4.5}
    {
        \node [circle,draw=white,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.5mm] (u\x\y) at (\x,\y)  {};
    }
%Drawing arrows
\foreach \y in {1.5,3.5}
    {
        \draw[semithick,->] (u1/2\y) -- (u1\number\numexpr\y-0.5\relax) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A dot in a node name has special meaning. It represents the anchor declaration for example `(a.45)` or `(b.west)`. Here it is causing trouble. I would strongly recommend not using numbers in node names in that way

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you drawing invisible nodes instead of using \coordinate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as one should not use x[2.5] in a C program, one should avoid using Tikz names with floating point numbers (converted to text).  But one can obtain the desired effect using Tikz arrays (not to be confused with LaTeX arrays).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Putting node and clipping them to their respective positions
\def\xval{{1/2,1,10/3,37/3,15.5}}
\def\yval{{1,1.25,1.5,3,3.5,4,4.5}}
\foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
    {
        \node [circle,draw=white,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1.5mm] (u\x*\y) at (\xval[\x],\yval[\y])  {};
    }
%Drawing arrows
\foreach \y in {2,4}
    {
        \draw[semithick,->] (u1*\y) -- (u1*\number\numexpr\y-1\relax) ;
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```